# No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid in webhost

Tags: laravel-5

my project worked well in localhost but it doesn't worked in web. 
after upload my project it give me this error

```
No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.
in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 31
at EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(object(Application), array()) in Container.php line 735
at Container->build(object(Closure), array()) in Container.php line
```

bla bla bla bla

some of tutorial says run command `php artisan key:generate` but doesn't make me any sense how could that in webhost ?
i can run any command in localhost but how can i do that in webhost?
or Is there any other options to overflow.?

Comment: In most cases (98%) you are not able to run commands in web hosts because in there exists a shared environment where a lot of users are hosting their applications in the same server. So, for that reason the terminal/console is disabled. Your web host must be a VPS or dedicated to connect to it via ssh.

Comment: is there any way without command line?
i just want to see my project online.

Comment: Try this. Go to `.env` file a set `APP_KEY` like `APP_KEY=DtPVUneeRNLd436ujoH2aW12hvj0T4dX`, and go to `config/app.php` file and set the cypher as  `'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'`

Comment: where did i found the `APP_KEY` ? in my localhost if i command `php artisan key:generate` it generate a key. but this key won't work on web-host.

Comment: APP_KEY is random string, you can set it manually as you prefer, I just shared you the mine.  - Too difficult make it works without commands

Comment: I also try that, still same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to your webserver using FTP (or equivalent) and find the `.env` file. More than likely, this will be a copy of of the one you've used on `localhost`.

The easiest way to fix this error is to find the line that starts with `APP_KEY` and make sure it's 32 characters in length. If it's not, just add some random characters to make it 32 characters.

If you can't find the line starting with `APP_KEY`, copy the line from your localhost `.env` file and just user it on the webserver.